# How to insert UILabel after UITextField in UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uilabel, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIAlertController` of `.alert` style with message text. I have inserted a `UITextFiled` in it with `addTextField(....` and now I want a string of text below it. I assume I need a `UILabel` but how do I insert it?

Comment: Might want to look into this library: https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UIAlertController` sub-classes from `UIViewController`. Because of this, a `UIAlertController` contains a view which can be modified. So, to add a label to the alert, you could do this:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
label.text = "Text"
alert.view.addSubview(label)
```

However, you should keep in mind what is [said in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller#1968629):

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.