# How to add UILabel into UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, alert, uialertcontroller

I tried to add UILabel into AlertController but it couldnt display on Alert.
I can make it for UIImageView but I couldnt it for UILabel. This followings are my code snippet

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: meta.name!, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction( UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil) )
   var sizeLabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 50, height: 50))
    sizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    sizeLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    sizeLabel.sizeToFit()
    sizeLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = alert.view.frame.size.width
    sizeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)
    sizeLabel.text = "Hello IOS"

    alert.view.addSubview(sizeLabel)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050057/8722754

Comment: I tried it already and My code is very similar also. But it doesnt work. It is never display my label

Answer (score 1):

So after some quick research it looks like you can't directly add a label to a `UIAlertController`. You can, however, use AttributedStrings. I used the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30661824/8722754 for my inspiration and updated it to Swift 3:

```
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "My Message",
         attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)!])

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage") is undocumented so may not be supported in the future and could result in your app not being approved by Apple store.